# How to disable scientific notation for small numbers in FastAPI + Postgres

Tags: python, reactjs, postgresql, fastapi

In my PostgreSQL database, I have a numeric type column with very small numbers (e.g. `0.000000022385`). I have a FastAPI endpoint which returns this data like so:

```
@app.get("/data", response_model=List[models.Data_Read], tags=["DataModel"])
async def getall_data():
    with Session(database.engine) as session:
        query = select(models.data_row)
        results = session.exec(query).all()
        return results
```

When I access this endpoint's return value in my React front-end, it shows up like `2.2385e-8`. I want to avoid all such instances. I have tried to do it on the front-end but haven't found any robust method. Instead, I have to apply a workaround to every single such value. Is there any way I can achieve this in FastAPI or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use f-strings to deal with this. More specifically, you can use the `:.#f` syntax. Any decimals more precise than the number you specify will be rounded.

e.g.:

```
small_num = 0.000000022385
print(f"Unformatted: {small_num}")
print(f"Formatted: {small_num:.12f}")

more_precise_small_num = 0.000000022385987987897897
print(f"more_precise_small_num: {more_precise_small_num:.12f}")
```

Output:

```
Unformatted: 2.2385e-08
Formatted: 0.000000022385
more_precise_small_num: 0.000000022386
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by converting the numeric number column to a string representation.
A way to do this can be to modify the FastAPI endpoint to change the format of the numeric values before returning them. The `format()` or the `str()` function in Python can achieve this.